# Verilog, how to do the same thing below if i got parameter?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
input [31:0]  dividend, divider;
dividend_copy = (!sign || !dividend[31]) ? 
                        {32'd0,dividend} : 
                        {32'd0,~dividend + 1'b1};
```

this one fix with value, if i want change to parameter
likes this:

```
Parameter: WIDTH = 32
input: input [WIDTH-1:0] dividend, divider;
```

so the divident_copy also need change but
 32'd0 i cannot figure out how to i change it.
Anyone can give me some tips, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the *replication operator*: `{ {  }}`, eg:

```
Parameter: WIDTH = 32
input: input [WIDTH-1:0] dividend, divider; 
dividend_copy = (!sign || !dividend[WIDTH-1]) ? 
                        { { WIDTH { 1'b0 }},  dividend} : 
                        { { WIDTH { 1'b0 }}, ~dividend + 1'b1};
```

The replication operator replicates whatever is in the inner set of curly-brackets by whatever number is between the first curly-bracket and the second.

Comment: the other way SV is to use cast: `typedef logic [WIDTH-1:0] T;` and `{T'(1'b0), dividend}`